# Is there a better way to install Jasper?

Tags: compiling

I have been trying to install Jasper on Ubuntu but it throws some "BS" errors. So I am turning to the more experiences after a year and a half.

It relies on TTS engines, however the bugs range from G++ throwing Errors that make the script uncompilable (stating that a defined term is undefined, etc).

Google TTS throws an Error 403 even with a valid API key!

Is there a better way to install it on Ubuntu, or is the project no longer supported?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? If it's 18.04, what happens when you run `sudo apt install jasper`?

Comment: Jasper is a github project, they have only a AUR package, but support debian in general.